# Input type file not opening window to select file

Tags: javascript, file-io, mmenu

Going through the mmenu website I set up a simple page using the "all" js and css files, having the menu open with a form in it that contains an input:file, the default input ui is shown, but fails to open a window (to select a file) when clicked on

note: the click event si fired it just doesnt show the explorer window

failed to work both on ff and ie (latest versions)

any help solving this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what you have tried yet?...make a fiddle or put some code here

Comment: No example or source code **=** no way for us to find the reason for this problem. How do you expect anyone to help you without the relevant information?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for lacking any code samples in the question.

After hours of playing around, the solution was simple.

mmenu listens to all click events and operates on them (doing whatever), so simply registering a click listener on the input and preventing it from bubbling did the trick. ( register listener, stop propagation, return true before mmenu captures and handles it )